# Graylog not consuming plain text log file completely

Tags: java, mongodb, elasticsearch, graylog

i have a problem using Graylog, i've been trying to ingest plain log file which contains lines of messages; However, i found out that Graylog not consuming log files content completely; I.e. Graylog only consume 800 from 1000 lines of messages in a log file;

I took a look on every component's log and found no error message;

I checked via web console, everything is fine with green condition (Elasticsearch shard)

Below is my setup in a single node machine

---

### Machine Info

- CentOS release 6.7 (Final)
- CPU core : 3
- Memory Total : 12GB

However, there are more than one application running in this machine, so i have limited resource here, which is probably fine, since i was trying to setup Graylog for POC purpose;

---

### Application workflow

There will be about 60 remote machine clients and each of them will generate log files (about 24MB / file / hour), this log file contains message that need to be ingested by Graylog for Support service needs.

As for production mode, i thought about custom collector using Nifi, fetching log files via ftp to our Graylog server. For POC, we will be using single machine for deploying Graylog core and web UI, MongoDB and ElasticSearch and we only need to simulate ingesting log files that already reside in Graylog server's local directory; I am using NX Log to consume the file and throw GELF as the output to be processed later by Graylog core.

The log files suppose to be ingested quickly (real time) by Graylog, however, as i stated previously, Graylog seems like stopped in the middle of task, this issue happened before and i just restart everything and Graylog resumed its task, unfortunately i didn't check the completeness.

---

### Graylog's configuration files

elasticsearch.yml : http://pastebin.com/eerR9LNb

nxlog.conf : http://pastebin.com/cN20rFnr

server.conf : http://pastebin.com/Nqp44wBH

collector-sidecar.yml : http://pastebin.com/YkbX4Mh9

---

### Graylog's configuration setup via web console

**Input**

Raw / Plain GELF UDP
Receive buffer size 1048576
Decompressed size limit 8388608

**Collector sidecar configuration**

I added Input and Output for NX Logs here, and only config dependent variables like URL, port, input file format (regex), etc, and i didn't touch any checklist box

**Decorator**

My partner used decorator with format string +${ORIG_ADDRESS_ADDRESS} and target field ORIG_ADDRESS_ADDRESS

**Extractor**

Again, my partner used an extractor, and when he realized about this current issue, he removed the extractor, and found that this issue still happened

Comment: For reference, the thread on the Graylog mailing list: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/graylog2/ZyCdg2vzyU0/G8R9n9uGBAAJ

Comment: Nah, that was me also,